# Problem changing settings in desktop and programs in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, unity, desktop-environments, settings, deja-dup

I had Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. installed, but it wasn't very stable, so I installed Ubuntu LTS 12.04 in its place, removing everything from /, but keeping /home.

Now I have several, but possibly related problems. A list of things I have noticed thus far:

1. I cannot change the background picture. It simply won't change regardless of what is chosen from the menu.
2. Changes to Unity sidebar do not persist between logins. The default icons return at every login.
3. Changes to Deja dup do not happen - if I open the settings panel and close it again, the changes are gone. Backup can be started, but does nothing.

I tried removing settings from the desktop, but returning everything to default settings did just that, without removing the problem.

However, I have no problems installing new software or changing Compiz settings or having those persist.

Comment: It could have something to do with old config files left in the `/Home` directory. Open this directory and hit `Ctrl+H` to make hidden folders visible (They will all be named in this manner `.Name`, e.g: `.android` `.cinnamon` `.gnome` on my system) You could try deleting these files for the applications you're having trouble with and then reboot your computer.

Comment: I also thought that could be the case, and removed all the files that seemed relevant. Are there any specific ones I should be looking at, based on the problems I'm having?

Comment: I have no idea about specific files sorry, I've only used this method to fix an Opera install after an update.

Comment: Tried purging and re-installing `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity`, didn't help.

Comment: Purging and re-installing `deja-dup` and `duplicity` didn't help with 3. either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a partial solution, but since I did not manage to find the specific files responsible for the problems, but I **removed all config files from /home and the problem was gone.** First, of course, I got copies of everything. I could test and see where the problem was, but that would take a lot of work.

Comment: for me, it was a simple permissions issue on `~/.config/dconf/user` which was owned by root after doing upgrade. Changing the owner back to my user fixed all issues.